# Error while logging in with facebook if the account contain second email

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-login

Error while logging with facebook if the account contains two email ( the main email and the second email ) any ideas ?

Comment: What is your scenario? Could you post your code and error here?

Comment: @HsenMchaimech you have to provide some context for your question, otherwise it'll be difficult to help you solve your issue.

Comment: Ill give u an example : if i have a facebook account with an old email address( i mean with old email address that  is inactive by hotmail) , but this account work well when u go and log in on Faceboook.com , otherwise  when u log in with this account via android app there's no email address returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand what you mean in your question, but I will mention that to the Facebook documentation for permissions:

email

Provides access to the person's primary email address via the email property on the user object.

Do not spam users. Your use of email must comply with both Facebook policies and with the CAN-SPAM Act.

Note, even if you request the email permission it is not guaranteed you will get an email address. For example, if someone signed up for Facebook with a phone number instead of an email address, the email field may be empty.

for reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0